# What does the phrase "shake a chicken (in the middle of the room)" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

The [1957 song *'Let's Have a Party'* by Jessie Mae Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Have_a_Party) includes the lyric:

> I've never kissed a bear, I've never kissed a goon,
>
> But I can shake a chicken in the middle of the room.

What does the phrase **shake a chicken** refer to? From the context of the song, it seems like it might be a dance; other places guess along the lines of voodoo or something more overtly sexual.

For context, there is [a clip of the line from the song](https://youtu.be/BPXD8d1ht-s?t=37) from the film *Party*, starring Elvis Presley.

Comment: As these are song lyrics were most anything goes, the answers are going to tend towards opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 'Shake a chicken' is probably a reference to the dance style, the Chicken

[The Chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_(dance)) was a style (or styles*) of dance:

> The Chicken is a popular rhythm and blues dance started in America in the 1950s, in which the dancers flapped their arms and kicked back their feet in an imitation of a chicken. The dance featured lateral body movements. It was used primarily as a change of pace step while doing the Twist.

Confusingly, it is different from the similarly-named [*Chicken Dance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_Dance) (also known as *Bird Song* or *Chicken Song*), which features accordion music and is likely the better known. A recording of this song, *The Birdie Song* charted in the UK in 1981.

Given the content of the song involves preparations for, and various actions at, a party it is reasonable to assume that the lyrics refers to a dance which was contemporaneously gaining popularity in the United States.

---

<sup>*: [Another source claims](https://www.rockinswing.com/single-post/2015/09/21/1950s-Dance-Styles-That-Didnt-Make-It-Into-The-Rockabilly-Scene-Yet) that *"The Chicken is actually the name of several completely different dances.  According to Manny Interiano of the “KPIX Dance Party”, it was basically a swing dance/cha cha variation."*</sup>

Comment: Given that “shake” has a strong connotation with sex, I think that “shaking a chicken” is much more likely to mean “have sex with a woman”  https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/7wrqd6a

Comment: @user5768790 I find it highly unlikely that _modern day_ slang would explain why singer, including female ones (Jessie Mae Robinson, Wanda Jackson) would mean that they were able publicly to have sex with a woman. Given the time this song was written, it would not have received a very positive response by the public and it would most likely have been banned. Apart from that, although _chick_ is a common (pejorative) reference to a woman, I am not aware of _chicken_ being commonly used in that sense.

Comment: +1 for the answer - the whole song is about having a party, which would likely include references to common occurrences at parties at the time, i.e. eating, drinking and dancing.

Comment: @oerkelens -  chicken  has a long history as a slang peggiorative term for woman: https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/bbbmfny. I think the expression plays on double meaning, and the sexual nuance does the trick.

Comment: @user5768790 that's an interesting angle- I didn't realise there was support for that sense in usage at the time; with the double meaning and subversion of 50's morals it's worthy of an A in its own right I reckon

Comment: Alternatively I can edit in your suggestion; but better you get the credit for it! :)

Comment: @user5768790 please add your analysis of these other lines from those lyrics [The meat is on the stove
The bread is gettin' hot
Everybody come and taste
The possum Poppa shot](http://www.cloverlyrics.com/e56012-elvis_presley~lets_have_a_party_lyrics.html)

Comment: @Mitch - I'll leave that to you...

Comment: @user5768790 I dare not, like the poor cat i' th' adage.